# How do I center text in flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, center

Why the texts are not at the center in the below code? (Title & Tag Line).

It should be like, [image: see image]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2em;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #000fe6, #000);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 80%;
  animation: animate 3.75s linear infinite;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(45, 45, 45, .05);
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    background-position: -500%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 500%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <p>Title</p>
    <p>Tag Line</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Why the texts are not at the center in the above code? (Title & Tag Line)

It should be like, [image: see image]

Comment: why don't you put a `text-align: center;` in your `p` rules  ?

Comment: add text-align:center to the div tag or your body tag

Comment: To expand on the above comments - it's because your flex only aligns the div to centre and makes the div as big as it's content - the divs content is left aligned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this in your `p`

```
 margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 2em;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #000fe6, #000);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 80%;
  animation: animate 3.75s linear infinite;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(45, 45, 45, .05);
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    background-position: -500%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 500%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <p>Title</p>
    <p>Tag Line</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: How can the text be smaller when screen is smaller (not going to the next line) in the above code?

Comment: for that you have to use `@media` and change the `font-size` in your css. [refer this link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: But how to do that automatically, every time? Shrinking the text automatically

Comment: you have to write style for multiple for eg:`@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  p {
    font-size: 80px;
  }
}` and `@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  div.example {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}` otherwise refer this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_responsive_text.asp) surely it will helps you

Comment: I tried `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`, but it is not happening: https://jsfiddle.net/08rpdLut/1/

Answer (score 1):

You have to align the p's content too. You can do it with **text-align: center** or with **display:flex** + **justify-content:center**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2em;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #000fe6, #000);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 80%;
  animation: animate 3.75s linear infinite;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(45, 45, 45, .05);
  text-align: center;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    background-position: -500%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 500%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <p>Title</p>
    <p>Tag Line</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add css

> `text-align:center`

in `body` or `p` tag